# How to Add Undo and redo option to Vue Editor Js?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex, undo-redo, editorjs

Front-end: Vue Js
Backend: Laravel Api
Editor: https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-editor-js

In editor.js, on every change request sent to DB.Now want to add redo and undo option,In core editor.js there is option but in Vue it is not working.
Also I am trying to store it in localstorage (VUEX) .
Any possible Solution?